# Codeigniter url routing limits

Tags: codeigniter, url-routing

I have an Codeigniter application with many many URL-s.

My question, is: How many rules can be defined to not affect the perfomance?

Comment: you probably talking about many many as product?id=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10
you can have them as much as you want.. otherwise there are no preformance problems

Comment: @IlanHasanov no, i mean how many rules can be definde in routes.php as `$route['url_1'] = 'controller/something'; $route['url_1-something'] = 'controller/something/another_string';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > You can create **100+** (*unlimited as simply*) URL routing. it will not ***affect to your system or Performance***.
> >
> > **Because only one URL call at time**

[Codeigniter routing](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)

Comment: sure, one ULR call at time, but searching the matched rule take time. It is fast enough?

Comment: @vasilenicusor No men ***its damm fast that you think***. Its get **500ms** to execute. its depend on you page content

Comment: so, with 1000 rules will be no problem? I have a requirement to implement the posibility to create a rule and assign a description,title - this will be displayed in browser according to route rule

Comment: no just. in my project also i used this. no delay at all